# Modification of value in switch case

Tags: java, initialization, switch-statement

```
public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 9;
    switch (i) {
    default:
        System.out.println("default");
    case 0:
        System.out.println("zero");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("one");
    case 2:
        System.out.println("two");
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
default
zero
```

Although `i` was initialized as 9, how is it possible that case 0 was picked? What is the reason?

Comment: Prints `default` `zero` for me.

Comment: If you `didn't` break after case. It will execute all `case` until you use `break`

Comment: So, the honest answer is: you don't understand the concept switch/cases. Thus, the message to take away here (besides not forgetting about putting breaks there): as a programmer, you **always** have to understand the concepts you are using. In other words: study, study, study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss a break statement after the first default case so the excution just falls through to the second case.Also put the Default case last so that it is only excuted after all the other cases are checked.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 9;
        switch (i) {

        case 0:
            System.out.println("zero");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("one");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("two");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("default");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And that solution does print "default" all the time, no matter what you put in i. Maybe worth mentioning that.

Answer (score 3):

When I ran this, it printed:

```
default  
zero
```

You have a couple things wrong.

**(1)** Put the default case at the end, not beginning. Otherwise you'll automatically go into the default case.
**(2)** Put a break statement after each case. If you don't, you code will continue from the case without the break and execute the code from the next case (and the next) until it reaches a break.

Try this

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 9;
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("zero");
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.println("one");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("two");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("default");
        }
    }
}
```

Link on Java switch statements --http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/switch_statement_in_java.htm.

Comment: No need for `break`at the `default` case since it is the last statement and nothing else executes after it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You missed using `break` in your default case thus the program continues to execution and prints "zero".

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two mistakes.

1. you should place the default case always at the end
2. you are missing important `break`s

**Solution:**

```
public class Sample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i = 9;
        switch (i) 
        {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("zero");
                break;
            case 1:
               System.out.println("one");
               break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("two");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("default");
        }
    }
}
```